# Odoo : Can not run odoo when using PostgreSQL DB as docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My developpement environment is using Pycharm, WSL 2 and docker.
The odoo folders are inside windows, the interpreters are inside WSL 2, the databases are both in WSL and docker
It works fine when I'm using the postgresql inside the WSL 2, it goes crazy when I use the postgresql inside docker.
I have tried many version of images : 9.5, 9.6 and 10.4 and I always get these [errors][1].
I also checked and try those solutions on github : 
https://github.com/odoo/docker/issues/221 
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/27447
I also changed the psycopg2 version but get the same error
I used this command to run the image :

```
docker run -d --name postgres.9.6 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -p 5436:5432 4bb112d23234
```

ps : Ubuntu 20.04, Windows 20H2, Docker 19.03.8

Could not initiate the db with -i base

Comment: your question is not clear at all

Comment: @kerbrose let me fix that

Comment: you also need to provide your `Dockerfile` & `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/9.5/images/sha256-2196c8fa2fa9821d2bd1f7b5e36d4be9a23c531f97e8db3cd36621eb4b4b6765?context=explore

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/9.6-alpine/images/sha256-bae81b1ad4fd0df90377253a98ac848a35cf9de5bf10ba4456bce74c9ebb4a7c?context=explore

Comment: I didn't ask for these files, I asked for your `Dockerfile` definition.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/10-alpine/images/sha256-dfec850b9ec6897aa482e4a3b3422e00d875ef05c7bd47e327b0478303b2b1c6?context=explore

Comment: @kerbrose How to get the Dockerfile If i just pulled those images then run it?